# How to hide an <a href> tag in InnerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have an image that has an InnerHTML for "a href" tag define in the .cs file as shown below.

```
_divToolTipContainer.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('" + btnItemThumbnail.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") + "','')\">" +
                                           itemimage;
```

Now what I want is to have this "a href" tag "hide" or "set visible to false" if the textbox is empty otherwise have this  click-able.

My code is shown below, but its not working.

```
    var oDivA1 = document.getElementById(oElementId);

    if(val === undefined || val == null || val.length <= 0){        
        oDivA1.style.display = "none"; // not working
    }else{
        oDivA1.style.display = "block"; // not working
    }
```

oDivA1.style.display = "none", this display none for the entire div not the "a href" tag only.

Is that possible?

Thanks

RJ

Comment: You're not closing your anchor tag, at least, not with the code you've shown.

Comment: the `innerHTML` javascript method shouldn't be capitalized, but the word `HTML` needs to be uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `firstChild` property to get the inner element of the div, assuming that's all the HTML it contains as shown in your example.

```
var oDivA1 = document.getElementById(oElementId);
var anchor = oDivA1 ? oDivA1.firstChild : null;

if(anchor && (val === undefined || val == null || val.length <= 0)){        
    anchor.style.display = "none";
}else{
    anchor.style.display = "block";
}
```

To prevent the link action

```
var handler = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };

if(anchor && (val === undefined || val == null || val.length <= 0)){        
    anchor.addEventListener('click',handler,false);
}else{
    anchor.removeEventListener('click',handler,false);
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener for information on browser compatibility and workarounds for older browsers.

Comment: Note - this is highly dependent on the exact markup you've shown and, potentially, the browser if you change your markup to include whitespace.  You might want to investigate using a framework such as jQuery to help with this.

Comment: it works fine, but the entire image was disappeared.  I just want to have the a href be unclickable something like that... Is there a better way? thanks

Comment: @user1306165 - yes, you could add a click handler that prevents the default action, or if the effect is permanent, you could remove the anchor tag and replace the content of the div with the anchor tag's innerHTML.

Comment: how? this is my 1st time to do this... waaaaaaaaa :(

Comment: @user1306165 - updated example, but really look at using jQuery for a better cross-browser solution.

Comment: Tried the code above, in deed it worked somehow but when the either cases if the textbox has a value or non the  a href is not working.  It will not do the postback anymore...